# Why give mysql group the same GID as sudo group?

Tags: sudo, mysql, group

I'm following installation/setup instructions in the [MySQL Secure Deployment Guide](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-secure-deployment-guide/5.7/en/secure-deployment-install.html), which say to create the mysql group with:

```
groupadd -g 27 -o -r mysql
```

The `-o` permits adding a group with a non-unique GID. I checked /etc/group on my machine and the sudo group uses GID 27

```
sudo:x:27:ivan
```

I also checked another machine that's running a different Linux distro, and it has a different group (`dialout`) occupying GID 27.

What would the implications be of using a non-unique GID? Why might these instructions recommend doing so?

Comment: The `mysql` user should not have `sudo` rights.

Comment: This isn't authoritative, but my opinion is that the people writing that document chose 27 as an unused-to-them GID, unaware that other distributions might have a `sudo` group there. It seems to me to be their intention to create a separate `mysql` group of GID 27.

Comment: They (and you) didn't ask me, but I wouldn't forcefully create a group of a given GID *and also* include the `-o` flag to allow it to share a GID.

Comment: @JeffSchaller I think you're right. I just checked on another Linux machine I have, and it has a different group (`dialout`) occupying GID 27

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My reading of that documentation doesn't lead me to believe that the intention is to share the `sudo` group. It appears to me that the developers chose 27 because it was unused on their system, and that the intention was to create a new `mysql` group of GID 27. That belief is undermined by their addition of the `-o` flag to `groupadd`, though, as that explicitly allows a new group to share an existing GID, which would *not* be in the interests of separation of duties, and thus not of security.

If it was me, I would allow `groupadd` to select the GID; I'm not sure whether a system GID (one less than /etc/login.defs:GID_MIN) is required.

```
groupadd mysql
```

or

```
groupadd -r mysql
```

and then refer to the group with the `mysql` name and don't rely on the GID being 27. A quick [search of that doc for "27"](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/search/?d=222&p=1&q=27) doesn't come up with any matches other than the page you already found. There are no results for `chgrp`, and the only hit for `chown` is in the [Post Installation Setup](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-secure-deployment-guide/5.7/en/secure-deployment-post-install.html) where they use the group name in:

```
chown mysql:mysql /usr/local/mysql/mysql-files
```

and

```
chown mysql:mysql /usr/local/mysql/data
```

(I've adjusted the commands to show the full paths versus the relative ones from the doc).